# Exo Player taking too much time to load cloudfront cdn HLS url

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

We are using CloudFront as a CDN delivery of our content using signed cookie in ExoPlayer on our Android app. The content will take around 12 sec in playing. As we are using 6sec chunk for playlist. Is there any setting that we will enable to render the content faster?

As CloudFront is standard way of delivery of video content and we expect faster delivery of content withing 3 to 5 second.

Can anyone suggest any setting that we can do with ExoPlayer??

Any help really appricated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that the content is taking 12 seconds to start playing from when the user first clicks play - i.e. you are referring to the video start up time.

Most CDN's work on a 'pull' model, where the client requests the content and the CDN then stores it near the 'edge' so that it is available for the next client without having to go all the way back to the origin.

For this reason, the first users may experience slower start times than following users, so it is worth testing this.

You can also ensure you have low bandwidth renditions available in the HLS stream, as this allows the client to start with a low bandwidth for fast start and then 'step up' to higher bandwidth as the video progresses. You can see this effect on services like Netflix and YouTube as the quality of the video improves after the start.

Different CDN's do also have different coverage in different regions, so it may be worth experimenting with various CDN's for your target region(s).

You may also be referring to latency, or how far behind the live action a particular stream is, if you are looking at live events.

In this case, 12 seconds latency would actually be very good - it is not uncommon to see 30+ seconds latency on OTT live streams. There is quite a bit of work addressing OTT live streaming latency, with a number of protocols being proposed to address it including the ones below - many involve shorter segments for th elvdieo to allow playback start more quickly:

- Low latency HLS and DASH, building on CMAF (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/about_the_common_media_application_format_with_http_live_streaming)
- HESP Alliance (https://www.hespalliance.org)